How to force the response not started in ASP.NET Core middleware?
I'd like to create a fallback middleware to forward the request to an external service if it fails in original processing(500).
Here is my code:

FallbackMiddleware.cs

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();
    await _next(context); // returns 500
    if ((int)context.Response.StatusCode >= 500)
    {
       // calls an externeral service which returns 200        
       await _forwarder.SendAsync(context, "http://localhost:5002", _client);
    }
}


500Controller.cs

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
{
    return new StatusCodeResult(500);
}

The code above fails complaining that The request cannot be forwarded, the response has already started. So I searched and added this config in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddReverseProxy().AddTransforms(m =>
{
    m.AddResponseTransform(context =>
    {
        context.SuppressResponseBody = true;
        return default;
    });
});

However that config doesn't work as I expected, the error message remains. Is is really possible to force the response not start in a middleware? Or should I try other approach to implement this fallback model?
Referernce:

Retry of "Safe" HTTP requests


Firstly, I used Yarp.ReverseProxy package to resolve the IHttpForwarder couldn't be found error then I reproduced your issue System.InvalidOperationException: The request cannot be forwarded, the response has already started    at Yarp.ReverseProxy.Forwarder.HttpForwarder.SendAsync(HttpContext context, String destinationPrefix,, am I right here? Since you didn't share a complete sample or the nuget package references. I'm not sure if we are investigating the same thing.

@TinyWang Yes that is the correct package.

Is it necessary for you to use _forwarder.SendAsync to forward the request? I mean can we use httpclient to send http request directly when we get 500 error?

I had a simple test with codes below. In my test, when I hit an endpoint which return new StatusCodeResult(500);, then the middleware validation will go into the request forward part. Based on my test, if I de-comment the line return new StatusCodeResult(500); it will throw the exception again even if this line is put within context.Response.HasStarted == false condition. So that I could only "forward" the request by HttpClient manually which will work.
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;
    using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    context.Response.Body = memoryStream;

    try
    {
        await _next(context);
        if (context.Response.StatusCode >= 500 && !context.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            // Suppress the original response body (avoid sending it to client)
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //var result = await _forwarder.SendAsync(context, "https://localhost:7140/WeatherForecast", _client);
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7140/WeatherForecast")
            };
            var response = await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
                await response.Content.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
            }
        }
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
    }
}


